# Angular2: Push HTML Elements into DIV when windows is resized

Tags: angular

My Markup looks like this

```
<body>
<section>
  <div id="move1"></div>
  div id="content-goes-here-on-small-screen"></div>
  <div></div>
</section>
<aside id="move2">
  <p>ASDF</p>
</aside>
```

i want to move move1 and move2 into "content-goes-here-on-small-screen" when the windows is small than <640px

is there a good angular2 approach like a service to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

you can check window size by media query in css but if you want to check this using angular2 than you can use  `matchMedia` like this code

```
let mq = window.matchMedia("screen and (min-width:640px)")
    if (mq.matches) {
      // stuff goes here
    }
    else {
      // your stuff
    }
```